# Erreur dans as.igraph.vs(graph, v) : Invalid vertex name(s)

Tags: r, igraph

Using a igraph graph, I have a data frame of nodes of graph `g1`,

```
DC1<-data.frame(
node=V(g1)$name,
Frequency=DC1$'DC')
DC2<-DC1[order(-DC1$'Frequency'),]
```

I use a loop, and at each step I take the first node of the data frame. For this node I calculate its neighbors, and after I delete it and its neighbors from the graph and from the data frame.

The problem is at some step I have this message `

> Erreur dans as.igraph.vs(graph, v) : Invalid vertex name(s)`.

`

When I try to know why, I find that at this step the algorithm can't read the first row of the data frame, so I can't get the neighbors to continue the process.

```
while(length(get.edgelist(g1))>0){

 v<-DC2$node[(order(-DC2$'Frequency'))]
 L<-V(g1)[V(g1)$name==v[1]]

 Nei <- neighbors(g1,L,1)

}
```

Comment: Please update your post to make it reproducible. We don't have the graph `g1` so we can't currently run your posted code.

Comment: the problem is here :                                                                                    < > v<-DC2$node[(order(-DC2$'frequency')) ]
>  L<-V(g1)[V(g1)$name==v[1]]
> L
Vertex sequence:
[1] "125"
> Nei <- neighbors(g1,L,1)
> Nei
numeric(0)>                                                                                                                                                                         
 when i replace the <L> by its value, its works: >  > Nei <- neighbors(g1,125,1)
> Nei
[1]   28   30   76 1883
>